# Evaluate the integral in terms of areas.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image: Image attached]

I understand that the first one is 4 from basically adding the squares inside the signed area, but I'm unsure on how to proceed in getting the other integrals. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can't you find the second one? Same principle.

Comment: You are just finding the area under the graph on the given interval. It would probably help to divide it into triangles and rectangles.

Comment: How am I supposed to add up the squares between 2 and 5? The ones in between 0 and 2 were either full squares or half squares.

Comment: @etree Can you spot half a rectangle?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Usage of triangles and trapezoids helped out Jake, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some tricks to help you:

a. count squares

b. calculate the area of known figures, such as triangles and rectangles.

For example, the integral in (b) can be calculate as the same of the area of a trapezoid($(1+3)\cdot 2/2$), a rectangle ($1\cdot 3$), and a triangle ($3\cdot 2/2$) to give a grand total of $10$.

That should cover it, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define $y$ as a function of $x$ in the various intervals (it is simple since you have straight lines).

- For $0\leq x\leq 2$, $y=1+x$
- For $2\leq x\leq 3$, $y=3$
- For $3\leq x\leq 7$, $y=\frac{15}2-\frac{3}2x$
- For $7\leq x\leq 9$, $y=-\frac{13}2+\frac{1}2x$

You know that $$\int_a^b(\alpha+\beta x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2} (b-a) \big(\beta  (a+b)+2 \alpha \big)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score -1):

see the solution on your graph
[image]

Comment: While you're computing the values for the OP, you're not providing an explanation for how to compute those values.